# How many direwolves remain now at the end of Season 6?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Now at the end of "Game of Thrones" Season 6, how many of the direwolves the children were given in the first episode remain?

I suppose Arya's direwolf is still alive... but how about Jon's and the others?

(Yes I know this has been asked before, but we just finished the season, and numbers change...)

Comment: since when is aryas wolf still alive? I thought that one was killed in one of the first episodes spurning her hatred for that would be king?

Comment: @Thomas, nope, Arya threw rocks at her to chase her off but Lady was the one killed by Ned to appease Cersei.

Comment: Ah ok then I confused things there back then. txn!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

- Sansa's wolf, Lady: dead, killed by Ned Stark in season 1
- Arya's wolf, Nymeria: presumed alive, but not seen since season 1
- Robb's wolf, Grey Wind: dead, killed by soldiers at the Red Wedding in season 3
- Bran's wolf, Summer: dead, killed by wights in season 6
- Rickon's wolf, Shaggydog: dead, killed by Small Jon Umber in season 6
- Jon's wolf, Ghost: alive, last seen in season 6

Two are alive at the end of season 6, four are dead.

Source: [the Direwolves entry on the Game of Thrones Wikia](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Direwolves)

---

**The question is specifically about the end of season 6. The following information continues the answer into season 7. (Read at your own risk.)**

> Current direwolves that are still alive:

- > Arya's wolf, Nymeria: last seen in season 7 episode 2, leading a pack of wolves when encountering Arya. Arya accepts that her wolf is no longer a pet after the encounter.
- > Jon's wolf, Ghost: alive, but getting very little screen time.

Comment: Arya's wolf Nymeria, is very much alive in the books however - Arya keeps seeing the world through it's eyes in her dreams.  So hope that goes for the show too...

Comment: @BaardKopperud I know, the person who edited my answer put "presumed" there. But, the show does not follow the books anymore, so the edit is valid.

Comment: There is still hope that we might see undead Summer. So get hype, Wolfbowl might be coming

Answer (score 7):

Nymeria and Ghost are the only two we haven't been shown are dead in the show.

Comment: You haven't provided any evidence for this statement, and it doesn't add anything to the existing answer. I suggest you either flesh it out a bit, making it substantially different from Vahx's answer (e.g. by citing better sources), or delete it.

Comment: I posted it before his answer, and his doesn't have evidence either.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that your answer was first. It's still very short though, and doesn't cite any sources whatsoever, not even a semi-reliable one like GoT Wikia.

Comment: Sure, his is the better answer; I upvoted it myself.  That's how this whole stack thing works. ;)

Answer (score 1):

## Nymeria and Ghost

### Alive

- Jon Snow, Ghost: Last seen in Season 6 Episode 3, "Oathbreaker", presumably still alive and with Jon.

[image: Ghost defends Jon's corpse]

- Arya Stark, Nymeria: Last seen in Season 1 Episode 2, "The Kingsroad", after Nymeria defends Arya Stark from Joffery Baratheon, Arya Stark sends her away.

[image: Arya Stark hugs Nymeria a goodbye]

> However, as of Season 7 Episode 2, "Stormborn", Nymeria is seen when a pack of wolves she's leading is hunting Arya Stark.
>
>  [image: Arya Stark reunites with Nymeria]

### Dead

- Sansa Stark, Lady: Killed in Season 1 Episode 2, "The Kingsroad", by Eddard Stark on the order of King Robert Baratheon*.

[image: Eddard Stark comforting Lady before the execution]

- Robb Stark, Grey Wind: Killed in Season 3 Episode 9, "The Rains of Castamere", by Frey crossbowmen.

[image: Robb Stark with Grey Wind's head sewn on]

- Bran Stark, Summer: Killed in Season 6 Episode 5, "The Door", by wights defending Bran Stark.

[image: Summer defends Bran Stark]

- Rickon Stark, Shaggydog: Killed sometime before Season 6 Episode 3, "Oathbreaker", by Smalljon Umbers men. The head is given to Ramsay Bolton to prove the boy is Rickon Stark.

[image: Shaggydog's head]

---

<sup>* Technically Cersei Lannister ordered the execution through Robert Baratheon.</sup>