# Where is Ghost?

Tags: game-of-thrones

As of Season 7 Episode 2 of *Game of Thrones*, it seems we haven't seen Ghost since

> Jon was brought back to life at Castle Black

He also wasn't there for

> the Battle of the Bastards

either. **So where is he?**

Comment: [CGI is expensive you know](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-pdxI5Bbb-94/UzvwTXZ79EI/AAAAAAAAY7k/HXGh0b705OA/s1600/you+know.jpg)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**In Universe**, we do not know where Ghost is currently.  The actor who plays Davos theorised that the [battle is not a safe place for Ghost](https://winteriscoming.net/2016/06/21/liam-cunningham-davos-explains-why-ghost-wasnt-in-battle-of-the-bastards/), and so that's why he isn't included in the Battle of the Bastards.

> Yeah that would have been cool, [but] obviously a big battle like that is no place for a direwolf,” he said. “They’re not gonna last very long – I mean look at what happened to Wun Wun, the last of the giants.”

**I would assume that Ghost is with Jon (just off screen) but it's definitely possible that he is off hunting, or still at Castle Black.**

Obviously, this does not jive with book passages or previous scenes showing various direwolves in battle.

**Out of Universe**, [the director explained that Ghost was cut from that battle for budgetary reasons](http://time.com/4377207/game-of-thrones-ghost-battle-of-the-bastards/), the same reason that all of the direwolves' roles have diminished as the series has gone along.

> "[Ghost] was in there in spades originally, but it's also an incredibly time consuming and expensive character to bring to life," Sapochnik told Business Insider. "Ultimately we had to choose between Wun-Wun and the direwolf, so the dog bit the dust."

Interestingly enough, it seems that [Direwolves may be more expensive to create then the Dragons](https://www.vox.com/2017/7/23/16017680/game-of-thrones-arya-direwolf-nymeria-stormborn) (which also haven't made much of an appearance yet this season).

> Though the series showed a lot of the wolves in season one, their appearances have been noticeably rare in later seasons, with two being brought back in season six only to be unceremoniously killed off.
>
> That’s no accident. Game of Thrones has found that **now that the direwolves are big enough that they have to be CGI creations, they’re very expensive and difficult to animate.** (They seem to have been much more challenging than the dragons, perhaps because it’s more difficult to convincingly animate an animal that we expect to look and move like a real wolf.)

Out of Universe, this would continue to hold true for future episodes.  It's simply too expensive for them to film Ghost walking next to Jon as he goes about his daily routine.

Comment: Ghost budget went to Nymeria.

Comment: @Skooba wasn't a lot of budget tho.

Comment: The wolves in season 1 were real dogs actually, so there was no need for CGI... Sophie Turner actually adopted the dog that played Lady (or so i read on interwebz)

Comment: @Vahx yeah I saw the same thing. I wonder of GoT regrets making the dire wolves so big that they couldn't still be played by a dog. They look sweet now, but it almost seems like they're making major plot decisions based on avoiding putting a dire wolf in a scene.

Comment: "the same reason that all of the direwolves' roles have diminished as the season has gone along" Other than Nymeria's unexpected appearance, which other direwolves still exist? Isn't Ghost the only one? Lady was killed, Shaggydog's head was presented by Ramsay, Robb's DW was sown onto his corpse, and I can't remember what happend to Bran's but his DW has been absent from the story for a while now.

Comment: @Flater only two still survive. But if you look at the screen time for the wolves while they are living it has diminished. And compared to the books, they've really reduced the amount of "on screen" time for the direwolves.

Comment: @kuhl: I'm not saying you're wrong, I was merely arguing that there's no point referencing "all of the direwolves' roles have diminished" if there is only one direwolf still alive (again, excluding Nymeria's appearance in the last episode, as your statement seems to focus on _last_ season). You are right about avoiding unnecessary CGI costs, I'm not arguing that point :)

Comment: @Flater Made an edit.  The 'all the direwolves roles have diminished' was supposed to be in reference to the full series, not just this season.  I misspoke there.

Comment: @kuhl i don't think they choose to make the wolves so big :p they are described in the books, so they need to follow that at least a bit

Comment: @Flater “Other than Nymeria's unexpected appearance, which other direwolves still exist? Isn't Ghost the only one?” — [Correct.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135222/how-many-direwolves-remain-now-at-the-end-of-season-6/135225#135225)

Comment: Great answer! Thank you

Answer (score 13):

### **He's at Winterfell**

[**Brian Cogman**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_Cogman), who is one of the show's main writers (especially the writer of that particular episode) and co-executive producer [mentioned](https://twitter.com/b_cogman/status/889380832963567616) on Twitter that:

> FYI... We shot a Jon/Ghost scene. Didn't make it in. I tried! Thx for watching, everybody. #Stormborn

[image: Screenshot of Twitter post from writer and co-executive producer of the Game of Thrones TV show, Bryan Cogman, which reads: "FYI... We shot a Jon/Ghost scene. Didn't make it in. I tried! Thx for watching, everybody. #Stormborn".]

He goes on to [further say](https://twitter.com/b_cogman/status/889979051896487936):

> He's at Winterfell. The scene was a brief goodbye beat.

[image: A screenshot from a twitter reply from Bryan Cogman in reply to a user who asks: "Is Ghost still at Winterfell or did he go with Jon?" to which Bryan replies: "He's at Winterfell. The scene was a brief goodbye beat.".]

So that means that the good news is: once the DVD/Blu-Ray versions come out, we'll see that cut scene and hopefully get a better idea of where exactly Ghost is.